# Some bin intervals in the legend not colored with ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have the following [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clWT1.png)

However the bin representing the interval 2,3 is colored in white in the legend while my max value in my dataframe is 2.55.
So, I don't understand why?
I have tried to modify the breaks, the number of colors, nothing seems to work...

I have tried this:

```
# Define the values that have equal distance between each other
break_values <- seq(-3, 3, by = 0.2)

# Define the desired breaks
my_breaks <- c(-3, -2, -1, -0.5, -0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 3)

# Map the break values to the desired breaks using the cut() function
break_labels <- cut(break_values, breaks = my_breaks, include.lowest = TRUE)

# Set the colors for each break
my_colors <- c(
  "#67001f", "#b2182b", "#d6604d", "#f4a582", 
  "#bdbdbd",
  "#4393c3", "#2166ac", "#084594", "#053061"
)

# Plot the map with the custom breaks and colors
map1=ggplot(data = sif_min_sm2) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = cut(SIF_SM, breaks = my_breaks, include.lowest = TRUE))) +
  coord_equal() +
  labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = my_colors,
    labels = levels(break_labels),
    na.value = "white",
    name = "SIF anomalies",
  ) +
  ggtitle("Corresponding SIF for driest SM month") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
    legend.position = "right",
    legend.key.size = unit(1, "lines"), 
    legend.text = element_text(size = 8), 
    legend.key.height = unit(1, "cm"),
    legend.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5, b = 0, l = 0)
  )
```

snippet of my df:

```
structure(list(lon = c(-53.75, -53.25, -52.75, -52.25, -51.75, 
-51.25, -50.75, -50.25, -49.75, -49.25, -48.75), lat = c(-28.25, 
-28.25, -28.25, -28.25, -28.25, -28.25, -28.25, -28.25, -28.25, 
-28.25, -28.25), SIF_SM = c(2.55345014731089, -0.308750009536743, 
0.473372499148051, 0.276275843381882, 0.404755104333162, 0.200375850001971, 
-0.258405844370524, -0.501487548152606, -0.367008318503698, -0.158782511949539, 
-0.483018159866333)), row.names = 159373:159383, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example data I wasn't able to reproduce your issue. But my guess was that this happens because of `NA` values. Hence, I slightly adjusted your example data by adding a value which falls outside of the range of the breaks you used for `cut`, i.e. I replaced the first value by `4`.

Doing so I was able to reproduce your issue:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Plot the map with the custom breaks and colors
p <- ggplot(data = sif_min_sm2) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = cut(SIF_SM, breaks = my_breaks, include.lowest = TRUE))) +
  coord_equal() +
  labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") +
  ggtitle("Corresponding SIF for driest SM month") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
    legend.position = "right",
    legend.key.size = unit(1, "lines"), 
    legend.text = element_text(size = 8), 
    legend.key.height = unit(1, "cm"),
    legend.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5, b = 0, l = 0)
  )

p +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = my_colors,
    labels = levels(break_labels),
    na.value = "white",
    name = "SIF anomalies"
  )
```

[image]

Also, based on the answer by @tjebo when dropping the `labels` from `scale_fill_manual` shows that this is indeed related to the `NA`s which in that case show up as the legend label.

```r
p +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = my_colors,
    na.value = "white",
    name = "SIF anomalies"
  )
```

[image]

One option to fix that would be to explicitly set the limits which also ensures that the right colors are assigned to the bins. Nonetheless I would suggest to check the range of your data and if my guess was correct to adjust the binning:

```r
p +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = my_colors,
    labels = levels(break_labels),
    na.value = "white",
    name = "SIF anomalies",
    limits = levels(break_labels)
  )
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
sif_min_sm2 <- structure(list(lon = c(
  -53.75, -53.25, -52.75, -52.25, -51.75,
  -51.25, -50.75, -50.25, -49.75, -49.25, -48.75
), lat = c(
  -28.25,
  -28.25, -28.25, -28.25, -28.25, -28.25, -28.25, -28.25, -28.25,
  -28.25, -28.25
), SIF_SM = c(
  4,
  #2.55345014731089, 
  -0.308750009536743,
  0.473372499148051, 0.276275843381882, 0.404755104333162, 0.200375850001971,
  -0.258405844370524, -0.501487548152606, -0.367008318503698, 
  -0.158782511949539,
  -0.483018159866333
)), row.names = 159373:159383, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Perfect Stefan :)). I set the limits as suggested. Thank you very much !! On a similar note, I tried also this way ggplot(data = sif_min_sm2) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = SIF_SM)) +
  coord_equal() +
  labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colors = brewer.pal(9, "RdBu"),
    breaks = c(-3, -2,-1, -0.5,-0.2, 0, 0.2,0.5, 1, 2, 3),
    limits = c(-3, 3),
    na.value = "white",
    name = "SIF anomalies"
  ) but I could not find how to make all the spacing of intervals at an equal size regardless of their size in the data space ?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot fully reproduce the problem. I believe this might be related to your data. When using own self-produced data I don't run into that problem.

Of another note, when using your cuts as a fill aesthetic, you don't need to specify the labels in the scale_ function - it is possible that your actual problem might be buried here.

I am suggesting however to make use of `scale_binned` - no cuts needed, all ready made, and intuitive.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(x=rep(1:5, 6), y = rep(1:6, each = 5), value = rnorm(30, 0))

# Define the desired breaks
my_breaks <- c( -3, -2, -1, -0.5, -0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 3)

# Set the colors for each break
my_colors <- c(
  "#67001f", "#b2182b", "#d6604d", "#f4a582", 
  "#bdbdbd",
  "#4393c3", "#2166ac", "#084594", "#053061"
)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = cut(value, breaks = my_breaks, include.lowest = TRUE))) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = my_colors,
    ## remove labels if you're using cuts for your fill aesthetic anyways. 
    na.value = "white"
  )
```

[image]

```r
## NA added 
df$value[1] <- NA

## Alternatively, use scale_binned
ggplot(df) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value)) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_stepsn(breaks = my_breaks, limits = range(my_breaks), 
                    colors = my_colors, na.value = "white")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi @tjebo! Thank you very much for taking the time to dive into my issue. With the first approach, the NA values have a bin in the legend... and with the 2nd approach, it's good but I would rather like to set up my own breaks and the defined colors.

Comment: @herakles_1950 this is - of course - adjustable, and much easier than with cuts. See my adjusted answer for this.